# Calibrun.Micro Sample/Feature/UWP : What is "cm:Bind.Model="{Binding}"

Tags: c#, uwp

[Here is Calibrun.Micro example with UWP.](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/blob/master/samples/features/Features.UWP/Views/BubblingView.xaml)

[image]

in Bubbling sample, [in this file](http://Caliburn.Micro/samples/features/Features.UWP/Views/BubblingView.xaml),
there is this line

```
<Grid cm:Bind.Model="{Binding}">
```

What is mean ? Why does it necessary ?
I thought Next line is enough for send $dataContext

```
<Button x:Name="Message" cm:Message.Attach="SelectPhrase($dataContext)" Margin="0,12" />
```

Please advice me....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's analyze the code as quite some things are a bit obscure in Caliburn.Micro as it works through convention:

```
<Page
    x:Class="Features.CrossPlatform.Views.BubblingView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:cm="using:Caliburn.Micro"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <TextBlock Text="actions" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" Margin="40,10,40,0"/>
        <StackPanel Margin="40,20">
            <ItemsControl x:Name="Phrases">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid cm:Bind.Model="{Binding}">
                            <Button x:Name="Message" cm:Message.Attach="SelectPhrase($dataContext)" Margin="0,12" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

First of all, the page's datacontext (viewmodel) is set through naming convetion. This viewmodel can be found [here](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/blob/master/samples/features/Features.CrossPlatform.Shared/ViewModels/BubblingViewModel.cs). As you can see, this viewmodel has a `Phrases` property and a `SelectPhrase(MessageActivityViewModel phrase)` method.

If we go down the tree, we have an `<ItemsControl x:Name="Phrases">` which binds to the `Phrases` property, which is a collection of `MessageActivityViewModel`.

An `ItemsControl` needs a way to present the items, which is defined in the DataTemplate. This template has a `Grid` as root object. If the Grid would not use `{Binding}`, it would inherit the datacontext from the template, which is the current element being rendered (a single `MessageActivityViewModel`). **However, we want to call the `SelectPhrase` method on the `BubblingViewModel` and not on the `MessageActivityViewModel`.** To be able to do that, we use `{Binding}` to tell the Grid binds to the page's viewmodel instead of to the single rendered `MessageActivityViewModel`.

What the Button does, is sending the datacontext object (being the rendered `MessageActivityViewModel` item) back to your viewmodel.

> $dataContext:
>
> Passes the DataContext of the element that the ActionMessage is attached to. This is very useful in Master/Detail scenarios where the ActionMessage may bubble to a parent VM but needs to carry with it the child instance to be acted upon.

Source: http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/cheat-sheet

Comment: Thank you, Bart : ) I understand 95%.               if we re-write with this line (  <Grid cm:Bind.Model="{Binding}"> )  with full description , How to write ? Why simple {Binding} mean "MessageActivityViewModel" ?                or Is there another way to write like this (     SelectPhrase(MessageActivityViewModel.$dataContext)     ) ?

Comment: {Binding} means the BubblingViewModel from the page (not the MessageActivityViewModel). You can replace that with {Binding Path=DataContext, ElementName=MyPage} if you give your page a name.